# How to import an AvroKeyValueOutputFormat file into hive?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera, avro

My mapreduce writes an avro file with the AvroKeyValueOutputFormat but I'm having some troubles to import this file into hive.

How I have to define my schema in hive to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the AvroSerDe described in

http://goo.gl/TwsRTd

or you have to transform your output to the RowFormat that you are using in your defined hive table (again using another mapreduce job)

Regards

Martin

Answer (score 0):

The format of the AvroSerDe can be a little tricky. As long as you know the Avro schema though it tends to work wonders. Hopefully this example helps.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HIVEDATA
ROW FORMAT
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.literal'='
{
    "namespace": "originalname",
    "name": "feature_value",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "acct_id", "type": "long"},
        {"name": "feature_name", "type": ["null","string"], "default": null},
        {"name": "namespace", "type": ["null","string"], "default": null},
        {"name": "feature_value", "type": ["null","double"], "default": null}
    ]
}
')
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/hdfs/location'
;
```